# Angular and JSON, having trouble parsing for ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm horribly sorry if there is a post for this, I tried to search but didn't find a answer.

**Problem:**

I'm calling a web service and receiving not so well formed JSON data from a Dynamics Nav service:

**JSON:**

```
"[{\"type\":\"2\",\"number\":\"VHT3866\",\"location\":\"Delta\",\"destinationNo\":\"\",\"contactName\":\"Jesus\",\"shipToName\":\"Lord jesus\",\"highPriority\":\"false\",\"hasComment\":\"true\",\"assignedTo\":\"\",\"source\":\"\"},{\"type\":\"2\",\"number\":\"VHT3866\",\"location\":\"Delta\",\"destinationNo\":\"\",\"contactName\":\"Jesus\",\"shipToName\":\"Lord jesus\",\"highPriority\":\"false\",\"hasComment\":\"true\",\"assignedTo\":\"\",\"source\":\"\"}]"
```

I then take this JSON and use `angular.fromJson(json)` to get it properly.

It doesn't seem to change into an array of javascript objects, but just plain text.

However if I take the same JSON and just put it manually in like this:

```
var json = angular.fromJson(stringfromserver);
```

It turns into a proper javascript object and `ng-repeat` throws no error.

Comment: I found an answer on Quora:

---  Le Batoure,,
Angular from json is now strict so assuming that this string is from a trusted source you would have to use "eval()" plus surround the call in parenthesis for it to work

    var hatsData = angular.fromJson(eval("(" + hats + ")"))
---

Comment: You could answer yourself instead of just commenting. It is good to know. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm horribly new at this, answered the question :)

Comment: However it works for me just fine without `eval` in angular 1.3.0. Probaby it has to do something with your Lord Jesus :)

Comment: Lord Jesus was just inserted instead of the actual company name, didn't want to have that publicly displayed :)

My angular is actually 1.2.17, going to update it and see if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer on Quora:

--- Le Batoure,
Angular from json is now strict so assuming that this string is from a trusted source you would have to use "eval()" plus surround the call in parenthesis for it to work

### var hatsData = angular.fromJson(eval("(" + hats + ")"))

Answer (score 0):

If you bring your JSON from http request for example you don't need to use the fromJson method.

The JSON is automatically parsed by Angular and you can use it directly.